# Possible to create a shortcut or command to apply settings in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am wondering if it's possible to create a shortcut / command of some sort to apply certain settings in VS Code?

For my particular use case, I like my window zoom level set to -0.5. Setting it to 0 is way too big, and -1 is way too small. But the quick keyboard shortcuts using ⌘+ or ⌘- only step through round zoom levels.

If I ever change it, I then have to manually open up VS Code's settings json and set

```
"window.zoomLevel": -0.5
```

What I want is to create a quick keyboard shortcut or command palette task that instantly applies this specific setting for me.

Is this possible somehow? Thanks

Comment: if you only have 1 setting to change you can use [Setting Toggle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ho-Wan.setting-toggle)

Comment: or use [Setting Switcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JrgMeier.setting-switcher)